# Python String concatenation with in double quotes

Tags: python, string

I am using Python and reading values from properties file as shown below,

```
print config.get('DeviceSection', 'Device1.name');
d1=config.get('DeviceSection', 'Device1.name') 
print d1
```

My JSON is

```
{
    "device-id":"system",
    "open-config":{  
        "port":32767
    }
}
```

Now, I want to set device-id with the value i was getting from config file. 
What I tried was,

```
{
    "device-id":"+d1+",
    "open-config":{  
        "port":32767
    }
}
```

But value of `d1` is not substituting inside the string. Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Thats not how strings work in python. You could do `"device-id":d1,.....`

Comment: Actually i came from java back ground and searching for python help.

Comment: It is better to read [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) before asking here and then maybe referencing to it what you can not understand.

Comment: @Ammad thats cool. just letting you know thats not how they work. My other comment and the answer posted show how you can do what you're after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't a concatenation: you're not appending this to anything else.  It's only a value substitution.  Thus, you should (1) use the variable name, rather than a string; (2) leave out the concatenation attempt.

```
     "device-id": d1,
```

This should substitute the desired value of *varibale* `d1`.